# Backwards the migration close reason text is

Tags: bug, status-completed, migration, close-dialog

When choosing a migration path in the close dialog, the text associated with each option doesn't make sense when reading, since it puts the name of the site *first* and then the text "belongs on":

[image: Image of the close dialog for choosing a migration on Stack Overflow. Transcription of the options below.]

The options are:

> - meta.stackoverflow.com belongs on
>
>   - discussion, support, and feature requests for this site
> - superuser.com belongs on
>
>   - Q&A for computer enthusiasts and power users
> - tex.stackexchange.com belongs on
>
>   - Q&A for users of TeX, LaTeX, ConTeXt, and related typesetting systems
> - dba.stackexchange.com belongs on
>
>   - Q&A for database professionals who wish to improve their database skills and learn from others in the community
> - stats.stackexchange.com belongs on
>
>   - Q&A for people interested in statistics, machine learning, data analysis, data mining, and data visualization

Just for reference, here is the migration dialog for Worldbuilding which also shows the same word order:
[image: Image of the close dialog for choosing a migration on Worldbuilding. Transcription of the option below.]

> - worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com belongs on
>
>   - discussion, support, and feature requests for this site

Every other dialog window for migration I've looked at shows the same thing.

I don't think the word order makes sense. I read it as "This question meta.stackoverflow.com belongs on". While Yoda pleased may be, this not a natural reading order for us humans is.

If it instead is supposed to read "belongs on discussion, support, and feature requests for this sites" then I still find this sentence strange *and* the site name actually makes it read "meta.stackoverflow.com belongs on discussion, support, and feature requests for this sites" which is stranger still.

The more natural flow for me is "belongs on meta.stackoverflow.com". Just a couple of illustrations how that could look like:

Moving "belongs on" before the list:

[image: Example image of the close dialog for choosing a migration on Stack Overflow. "belongs on" moved before the entirelist of destinations and each now only shows the destination URL.]

Swapping the URL and the "belongs on" in each close reason:

[image: Example image of the close dialog for choosing a migration on Stack Overflow. The URL and "belongs on" have swapped places to read "belongs on meta.stackoverflow.com"]

The choices can still be reworded in other ways as long as they make sense when reading them. Right now, in my opinion, they don't form coherent choices.

Comment: For the record, I was going to write the beginning part of my post in the style of the choices but I found "*When a migration path in the close dialog choosing, the text associated with each option make sense when reading doesn't, since it the name of the site first and then the text "belongs to" puts*" detracts from the point more than it emphasises it because of how annoying it is to read.

Comment: Cross-meta duplicate: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/396259/7296893, marked status-review.

Comment: @ErikA well, damn. I didn't check Meta SO - I looked here if it was reported or not.

Comment: @VLAZ Not matter much  it does, a network wide problem it is.

Comment: A problem with this I have not, but this should probably be fixed for the normal humans indeed.

Comment: Yoda, it must be written for