# What is Meta's definition of a "more frivolous" post?

Tags: discussion, meta, scope

I was recently [advised of the purpose of meta being](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44188/how-do-i-participate-in-meta-and-not-die-trying):

for "more frivolous discussions"

> Meta Stack Exchange is a special place for suggestions, bugs, support
>   questions, and discussion about the Stack Exchange sites. It is the
>   only place where more frivolous discussions are allowed. Meta is also
>   harsh(er) to your feelings. That said, here are a few guidelines if
>   you'd like to keep your sanity and reputation points.

Looking through the last 50+ questions, I cannot seem to find things that seem even slightly frivolous?

What does "more frivolous" mean in this case?

Please cite some examples of what would be considered acceptable "more frivolous" posts?

Comment: In the old days there were some more fun posts - see things like the many memes of meta, as well as more lighthearted comments. Community standards are stricter than the old days somewhat

Answer (score 14):

> It is the only place where more frivolous discussions are allowed.

Strictly speaking, that doesn't mean *all* frivolous discussions are allowed. While Meta is different than it was before, when that post was written, we still have non-serious topics now and then:

- Contests, like [Who cut the cheese?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/316515/295232) and [Time for some more swag!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/318910/295232)
- Nearly everything tagged [winter-bash](/questions/tagged/winter-bash)

Also, serious topics here sometimes do have some frivolousness in them, e.g. yesterday's [Backwards the migration close reason text is](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/346184/295232). The way that question is written is unacceptable when describing a programming problem on Stack Overflow, and some users probably would consider downvoting it. Here, it's receiving bonus upvotes for style points (I assume).

Comment: Site-specific metas also often have stuff that is more towards the fun and frivolous end, like [photo competitions](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6491/march-2020-photo-competition-travel-favorites) and [topic challenges](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1194/announcing-the-return-of-the-topic-challenges-oct-nov-2019-the-epic-of-gilgame)

Comment: Exactly: the purpose of meta is not for more frivolous discussions. It just happens that a small amount of frivolity is tolerated here, while absolutely none is tolerated elsewhere. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/284390/why-do-we-hate-fun-at-stack-exchange

Answer (score 3):

I have never seen a post here that I think should be encouraged on the grounds that it is frivolous but OK.

If I see a question or answer that I think is frivolous, then to my mind it is not useful, and I downvote it.

[Dictionary.com defines frivolous as](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/frivolous):

> *adjective*
>
> 1. characterized by lack of seriousness or sense:
>
> *frivolous conduct*.
>
> 2. self-indulgently carefree; unconcerned about or lacking any serious purpose.
> 3. (of a person) given to trifling or undue levity:
>
> *a frivolous, empty-headed person*.
>
> 4. of little or no weight, worth, or importance; not worthy of serious notice:
>
> *a frivolous suggestion*.

Using definition 3 for another user would be outside the Code of Conduct but definitions 1, 2 and 4 look like they could be applied to posts.

Answer (score -10):

> *Looking through the last 50+ questions, I cannot seem to find things that seem even slightly frivolous?* @ina

and posted in the comments

> *In the old days there were some more fun posts - see things like the many memes of meta, as well as more lighthearted comments. Community standards are stricter than the old days somewhat* @JourneymanGeek

@JourneymanGeek or maybe in recent months users had been suspended one too many times for frivolous infractions (obviously excluding instances of cheating the system and online bullyism), and have taken their light-hearted attitude elsewhere?

Or maybe, @ina,  it has something to do with the Covid19? Thousands of people have died worldwide, [+18,000 in Italy](https://www.google.com/search?sxsrf=ALeKk03_mKf4RjDzKFwruVSJf3VhN-LEhA%3A1586512702281&ei=PkOQXqnkEPPixgPmvYLgBA&q=mortalit%C3%A0%20covid-19%20italia&oq=mortalit%C3%A0%20covid-19%20italia&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQA0oKCBcSBjEyLTEzMUoICBgSBDEyLTVQ5h9YmyNg3CdoAHAAeACAAY0BiAGFBZIBAzAuNZgBAKABAaoBB2d3cy13aXo&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwip-7OwzN3oAhVzsXEKHeaeAEwQ4dUDCAw&uact=5) alone,  [over 7,000 deaths in New York](https://www.google.com/search?sxsrf=ALeKk00nUQySZ4KOMIAz1t9h6nlDVZQNag%3A1586512708631&ei=REOQXtCNJuPYxgPpg6LwCw&q=deaths%20covid-19%20new%20york&oq=deaths%20covid-19%20new%20york&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQAzoFCAAQkQI6AggAOgQIABBDOgQIABAKOgUIABDNAko1CBcSMTdnMTQ4ZzE1NGcxNDFnMTU5ZzEzMmcxMjVnMTIwZzEzM2cxMzBnMTMzZzEyMGcxMjJKHQgYEhkxZzFnMWcxZzFnMWcxZzFnMWcxZzVnNWc2UODtAVjPwgJgkccCaABwAHgAgAGWAYgBtxiSAQQxLjI1mAEAoAEBqgEHZ3dzLXdperABAA&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwjQv7ezzN3oAhVjrHEKHemBCL4Q4dUDCAw&uact=5), and there are millions of people currently locked in their homes,  unable to see or embrace their parents, their own children or grandchildren. Maybe it's not the easiest of times to be cheerful and talk about unicorns and April Fool's Day.

Comment: I saw everything unfold. The posts that resulted in suspensions weren't merely light-hearted, but offensive. The suspensions were valid in those cases.

Comment: That's a bit of a pointed accusation to make - and pretty untrue. I believe appropriate, harmless, lighthearted fun is always good, especially used to reinforce an answer. Its also more likely to be closed by the community now. Insinuating that we suspend people for having a little harmless fun is kinda unfair.

Comment: To get one's mind off things for a short while, [one possibility is TechLead](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jCHTFClfj5k&lc=UgziR34aOZV74NfLaSt4AaABAg).

Comment: @JourneymanGeek "frivolous **infractions**" doesn't mean jokes, or being light hearted. Furthermore, it is astounding that the reason for the low morale (and participation) on MSE  is somehow due to stricter guidelines. Please, stop lying to yourself and to everyone else.

Comment: Hmm, well, in my case, i asked a dark mode UX question that had references to Star Wars and also posted my corgi next to my laptop on S/O darkmode but it just didn't show clearly. But got downvoted a ton for it. It was not offensive IMHO... it seemed perfectly frivolous.

Comment: Perhaps it was downvoted because it was *too* frivolous considering the period we find ourselves in. Timing is everything...